# Docker, link container's files to host

Tags: docker

I have a React App built with Docker :

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Build
COPY package*.json ./
COPY src ./src
COPY public ./public
COPY .env* ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

# Remove build material
RUN rm -f package.json
RUN rm -f package-lock.json
RUN rm -rf src
RUN rm -rf public
RUN rm -f .env
RUN rm -f .env.local

# Update host
CMD rm -rf /home/node/app/www/*;cp build/* /home/node/app/www
```

I'm building this image through a Gitlab CI / CD pipeline and launching it on my remote host with docker-compose :

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/myproject/www:production
    volumes:
      - /var/www:/home/node/app/www
```

I have Nginx running on my remote host that serves **/var/www** on port 80.

What I would like to do is my container to be bind to **/var/www**
ie: Each time I'm building and launching my image, **/var/www** gets updated by it.

My setup kinda work but I ran into issues, it doesn't refresh all the time for whatever reason.

Is there any better way to do so ?

Comment: I'd just run Node here; don't involve Docker at all.  If your goal is to convert some files on the host into other files on the host, Docker's filesystem isolation works against you.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. I'm using Docker to build my app and maintain the integrity of my sources through my deployment process. I don't want to use a simple scp command to upload the sources nor pull the full repo. I have other reasons to use it, I would like to know if what is the optimal config.